# Port Audio Won't Install Due to Deprecated Core Audio Functions

Tags: installation, core-audio, deprecated, portaudio

I've been trying to install Port Audio onto my Mac for a little bit and I've hit a brick wall. Every time I try to install it using:

```
./configure --disable-mac-universal && make
```

It exits with an error code of 1 because CoreAudio has deprecated functions. I heard that CoreAudio got broken, or otherwise messed with, during one of the recent updates, and perhaps that caused my problem? I'm not really sure what to try right now as I can't find a way to rollback the version of the Core Audio framework on my computer. Any suggestions you guys would have would be great.

Mac OSX 10.7.5
XCode 4.5.2
Latest PortAudio build

---

Actual error code:

`AVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSIZEOF_SHORT=2 -DSIZEOF_INT=4 -DSIZEOF_LONG=8 -DHAVE_NANOSLEEP=1 -DPA_USE_COREAUDIO=1 src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/hostapi/coreaudio/.libs/pa_mac_core.o
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'PaMacCore_GetChannelName':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:140: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetPropertyInfo' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2611)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:151: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:159: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:193: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'PaMacCore_GetBufferSizeRange':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:232: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'gatherDeviceInfo':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:361: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:1249)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:374: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:1270)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:393: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:1270)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:410: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:1270)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'ClipToDeviceBufferSize':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:445: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'CalculateFixedDeviceLatency':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:525: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:530: warning: 'AudioStreamGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:3023)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:534: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:538: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'CalculateDefaultDeviceLatencies':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:568: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'GetChannelInfo':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:597: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetPropertyInfo' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2611)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:604: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'InitializeDeviceInfo':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:670: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetPropertyInfo' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2611)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:677: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:684: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'UpdateSampleRateFromDeviceProperty':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1033: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'QueryUInt32DeviceProperty':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1062: warning: 'AudioDeviceGetProperty' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2640)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'SetupDevicePropertyListeners':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1120: warning: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2703)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1123: warning: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2703)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1125: warning: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2703)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1127: warning: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2703)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'CleanupDevicePropertyListeners':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1135: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2729)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1138: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2729)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1140: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2729)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1142: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2729)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'OpenAndSetupOneAudioUnit':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:1304: warning: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2703)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'AudioIOProc':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:2340: warning: 'AudioConverterFillBuffer' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioConverter.h:699)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:2519: warning: 'AudioConverterFillBuffer' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioConverter.h:699)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c: In function 'CloseStream':
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:2599: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2729)
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.c:2608: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:2729)
make: *** [src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core.lo] Error 1`

Comment: Maybe it would help if you actually read the error message. :-) The key words are **warnings being treated as errors** (about the fourth line of the wall of text you posted). If you want to ignore the deprecated functionality and still compile, turn off that flag when you compile.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do that! I'll look that up right, thanks.

Comment: You should add the portaudio tag to this question (maybe instead of "port", "core" and "install"). You should say what OS/version of XCode etc you are running and what sdks you have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If updating to the latest PortAudio SVN doesn't fix the issue, this is the suggestion from the mailing list:

Remove -Werror from the build script and replace it with -Wall

Or try adding -Wno-deprecated before -Werror

If you do try adding -Wno-deprecated please let us know how you go since this is currently the preferred option, although it hasn't been tested much yet.

By "build script" they mean configure.in, I believe.

Comment: First I tried both flags on just configure.ini, then I tried just the makefile, then I tried the flags on both the makefile and configure.ini and it still gave me the warnings.

Comment: After modifying configure.in, rerun ./configure, which should generate a new makefile (you may want to check to make sure). If it still doesn't work, you could remove the -Werror flags altogether and see if that works.

Comment: Using what you suggested I was able to get it to compile. I also had to run sudo make install after ./configure --disable-mac-universal && make

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (-w disables all warning in GCC)

```
CFLAGS=-w ./configure && make
```

I tried -Wno-depreacted, but it didn't work for me:

```
command line option "-Wno-deprecated" is valid for C++/Java/ObjC++ but not for C
```